# Prepend basename to text files

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm trying to insert the `basename` of a text file as a new line in the same file for an entire directory of files (all with different `basenames`). So file "*frog.txt*" with content:

```
asdf
wef
sdf
```

...becomes:

```
frog
asdf
wef
sdf
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I've voted to close this question because it appears to be a request for a recommendation for a tool or solution, rather than a request for assistance with your own code. This makes your question off-topic for StackOverflow. If that assessment was incorrect, and you do indeed want help writing your own code, then please [add your work so far to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43256944/edit) and I'll happily retract my close vote.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this bash one-liner:

```
for file in "sample1.txt" "sample2.txt"; do sed -i "1i${file%%.*}" "$file"; done
```

This will loop through each file name. `${file%%.*}` will remove extension from `$file`. Then `sed -i '1...'` will insert the filename (without extension) as first line.

Comment: For reference, this one-liner is not just Bash, it should work in any POSIX shell. The gotcha with your suggestion is that it assumes a particular version of `sed`, since the `-i` option works differently in sed from different operating systems. To be more portable, since the OP didn't specify an operating system, you should probably implement in-place functionality using redirection and `mv` within the script itself.

Comment: You might use `printf "1i\n%s\n.\nw\nq\n" "${file%%.*}" | ed -s "${file}" `.

Answer (score 0):

try this in the directory with your files:

```
for file in `ls`
do
# echo filename without extension to filename.tmp
# because you wrote .txt ${file:0:-4} removes 4 characters from the end
echo ${file:0:-4} >> $file".tmp"

# set IFS to split lines
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")

# echo line by line to filename.tmp
for line in `cat $file`
do
echo $line >> $file".tmp"
done 

# rename/move filenname.tmp to filename
mv $file".tmp" $file
done

# set IFS to normal
unset IFS
```